# JSON.parse result to proper array of objects

Tags: javascript, json

after my JSON.parse I have this data

```
 data = [
  {
      "serviceType": "service1",
      "method": "close",
      "quantity": 56
  },
  {
      "serviceType": "service1",
      "method": "divert",
      "quantity": 175
  },
  {
      "serviceType": "service1",
      "method": "reverted",
      "quantity": 80
  },
  {
      "serviceType": "service2",
      "method": "close",
      "quantity": 15
  },
  {
      "serviceType": "service2",
      "method": "divert",
      "quantity": 149
  },
  {
      "serviceType": "service2",
      "method": "reverted",
      "quantity": 149
  },
  {
      "serviceType": "service3",
      "method": "close",
      "quantity": 87
  },....
  }
]
```

And I need it to be like `data.json` from this [d3 example](https://bl.ocks.org/bricedev/0d95074b6d83a77dc3ad) where `categorie` is my `serviceType`, being it the first property of every object (1 object per serviceType) and then the second property of every object should be an array of objects with the method and quantity.

I've been using `forEach` for every object in `data` and I'm pushing the first of every `serviceType` OK (without the 2nd property). The problem is I don't know how to `update` the object `values` (second property) inside the right object (according to the current `serviceType`).

```
finalArray = [];
data.forEach(function (d, index) {
    var serviceType = d.serviceType;    
    const found = finalArray.some( el => el.serviceType === serviceType);
    if (!found) {
        var obj = createObj(d); //function returning an obj with the desired structure
        finalArray.push(obj);                
    }...
});
```

This is an example of how the conversion should end up being.

```
[
    {
        "serviceType": "service1", 
        "values": [
            {
                "quantity": 0, 
                "method": "close"
            }, 
            {
                "quantity": 4, 
                "method": "divert"
            }, 
            {
                "quantity": 12, 
                "method": "reverted"
            }, 
            {
                "quantity": 0, 
                "method": "checked"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "serviceType": "service2", 
        "values": [
            {
                "quantity": 1, 
                "method": "close"
            }, 
            {
                "quantity": 21, 
                "method": "divert"
            }, 
            {
                "quantity": 13, 
                "method": "reverted"
            },  
            {
                "quantity": 6, 
                "method": "checked"
            }
        ]
    }, ...
```

Comment: do you have an example of the wanted result?

Comment: @NinaScholz I edited the question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and group same `serviceType`. Later build an a array with `categorie` and `values` properties.

```js
var data = [{ serviceType: "service1", method: "close", quantity: 56 }, { serviceType: "service1", method: "divert", quantity: 175 }, { serviceType: "service1", method: "reverted", quantity: 80 }, { serviceType: "service2", method: "close", quantity: 15 }, { serviceType: "service2", method: "divert", quantity: 149 }, { serviceType: "service2", method: "reverted", quantity: 149 }, { serviceType: "service3", method: "close", quantity: 87 }],
    result = Array.from(
        data.reduce((m, { serviceType, ...o }) => m.set(serviceType, [...(m.get(serviceType) ||  []), o]), new Map),
        ([categorie, values]) => ({ categorie, values })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Neat, I'll dig into this to proper understand it, I'm not well versed in `Map`. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can get one object with grouped services using `reduce` method and then get array of values from that object.

```js
const data = [{"serviceType":"service1","method":"close","quantity":56},{"serviceType":"service1","method":"divert","quantity":175},{"serviceType":"service1","method":"reverted","quantity":80},{"serviceType":"service2","method":"close","quantity":15},{"serviceType":"service2","method":"divert","quantity":149},{"serviceType":"service2","method":"reverted","quantity":149},{"serviceType":"service3","method":"close","quantity":87}]

const object = data.reduce((r, {serviceType: s, ...rest}) => {
  if(!r[s]) r[s] = {categorie:s, values: [rest]};
  else r[s].values.push(rest);
  return r;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(object);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const result = [...new Set(data.map(e => e.serviceType))].map(serviceType => {
  const re = { serviceType };
  re.values = data
    .filter(e => e.serviceType === serviceType)
    .map(v => ({ method: v.method, quantity: v.quantity }));
  return re;
});
```

First I get all the serviceTypes (the part using `...new Set()`), then I create an object for each thereof consisting of the serviceType-name and the values, which I get by filtering out unrelated objects and dropping the serviceType-property of the related ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.reduce((acc, value) => {
    var {serviceType, method, quantity} = value;
    var foundExisting = acc.find(v => v.serviceType == serviceType);

    if(foundExisting){
        foundExisting.values.push({method, quantity})
    } else {
        acc.push({serviceType, values: [{method, quantity}]})
    }

    return acc;
}, [])
```